# How to create an array of objects Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object

Is it possible to create an array of objects in visual basic?

I'm making a battle system and whenever the battle begins, i wanna be able to randomly select a Monster object from an array.

If it is possible, could somebody show me how to store `Public Spider as New Monster(50, 20, 5)` into an array?

Thank you.

**Monster Class:**

```
Public Class Monster

  Private hp As Integer
  Private xp As Integer
  Private dmg As Integer

  Sub New(ByVal hitpoints As Integer, ByVal exp As Integer, ByVal damage As Integer)
    hp = hitpoints
    xp = exp
    dmg = damage
  End Sub

End Class
```

**Form Class:**

```
Imports Monster
Public Class Form

  Public Spider As New Monster(50, 20, 5)

End Class
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A [List(Of T)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=list%28of%20t%29&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F6sh2ey19.aspx&ei=yJqeUdGIC8yAygGK6IDQBg&usg=AFQjCNEDl4T3WgLBndZ1pncFdqEW4rkuog&bvm=bv.47008514,d.aWc) would work great for that.

```
Private Monsters As New List(Of Monster)
'later add them into this collection
Monsters.Add(New Monster(50, 20, 5))
```

Comment: Ooh, beat me to it :D. +1 for you.

Comment: It's hard to tell if more than one of us are answering at one time. I got beat yesterday. =)

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the `Collections` like `List(of Monster)` to hold it if you don't have a set and knowable number of class instances to store.

```
Dim Monsters As List(of Monster) = New List(of Monster)
Monsters.Add(New Monster(10, 50, 30))
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, ArrayList is better, but your question is useful too.

```
  Dim MonsterArr() As Monster = New MonsterArr(1000) {}
```

or

```
  Dim MonsterArr() As Monster = New MonsterArr(1000) {0,0,0}
```

or

```
  Dim MonsterArr() As Object = New Object(1000) {}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it